# SharePoint People Picker search only from Active Directory

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, people-picker

In sharepoint, when we search for users using "People Picker", it fetches the users from "User Information List" as well as Active Directory.

Now, the issue is that, if we disable a user in Active Directory & search in people picker, It still provides that user in search results (as that user is available in local sharepoint site collection cache).

I understand we can restrict people-picker to read filtered ACTIVE AD members using:

```
stsadm.exe -o setproperty -pn peoplepicker-searchadcustomfilter -pv "(!(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2))" -url http://siteurl
```

Also, there is another property for people picker to search only within site collection,

```
stsadm -o setproperty –url http://siteurl –pn peoplepicker-onlysearchwithinsitecollection –pv yes
```

We can always avoid users to be searched from People-Picker control by deleting them from site collection, but it is not what I want.

Is there any way, the People-Picker could be configured to search the users only from ActiveDirectory & not from site collection?

Comment: Would you be willing to share your custom people picker or how you made it? I am trying to achieve the same thing. I would like people picker to only search AD and ignore the UIL. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Not with the out of the box People Picker.  The People Picker will always parse the UIL prior to reaching out to other data sources.

Answer (score 0):

The Mysite clean up timer job should remove the users disabled in AD assuming that your user profile service is configured to import only active users and mysite cleanup timer job is running.
You can force remove the obsolete users using PowerShell as mentioned here:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff681014(v=office.15).aspx#RemoveObsUsers

Comment: This is not what we needed. We didn't want to remove disabled users from the site collection. We had to write custom People-Picker in order to achieve the same functionality.